# DataGridView.CellContentClick Event

Tags: .net, winforms

I've a datagridview and I have 5 columns. If I click any cell in 5th column, it will show me message for example.
I use `DataGridView.CellContentClick Event`

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

well you can start with some code like this:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.ColumnIndex == 4)
  {
    // here when the column index is 4, the first one is 0 so 4 means 5th column...
  }
}
```

check here in MSDN for all details and examples:

[DataGridView.CellContentClick Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

inside your click event:

```
if(e.ColumnIndex == 4)
{
  MessageBox.Show("message");
}
```

Or in VB:

```
If e.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
  MessageBox.Show("message")
End If
```